# Como filtrar texto html e exibir div conforme o texto encontrado

Tags: jquery, html

Salve lista!

To precisando de uma ajuda aqui
tenho as seguintes tags no html:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="div01" style="display: none">
    <p> esse texto está aqui para ser pesquisado.</p>
    <p> esse outro texto também vai ser pesquisado.</p>
    <p> texto que vai ser que o usuario vai pesquisar digitando no input.</p>
</div>
    <div id="div02" style="display: none">
    <p> esse paragrafo deve aparecer se o texto didigtado estiver nessa div.</p>
    <p> esse outro parágrafo vai obedece ao mesmo cirterio.</p>
    <p> o usuario vai digitar no input e essa div deve aparecer.</p>
</div>
        <div id="div...N" style="display: none">
    <p> aqui só tem palavras e frases.</p>
    <p> nesse os caracteres estão separados por espaço.</p>
    <p> escrever no campo deve mostrar esse bloco.</p>
</div>
<!-- ... -->
</body>
</html>
```

até aqui, consegui marcar o texto procurado com o seguinte codigo jquery, já tá funfando blz:

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function()
      {
        $("#textFind").keyup(function()
        {
          stringPesquisa = $("#textFind").val();
          $('P').css("background","");
          $('P:contains('+stringPesquisa+')').css("background","#FFFF00");
        });
      });
      function teste()
      {
        var a = document.getElementById('textFind').value();
        alert(a);
      }
    </script>
```

O que preciso é: quando o usuario digitar um texto no input e motor encontrar o texto digitado em uma div qualquer que vão ser inumeras, o codigo esconde todas as outras divs onde o texto não existe e mostra todas as que existe, que pode ser uma ou várias.
Exemplo:

digitar "texto" no input, deve esconder as divs "div02" e "div...N" e mostrar a div "div01"

digitar "input" no input, deve esconder a "div...N" e mostrar as divs "div01" e "div02"

digitar "caracteres" no input, deve esconder as divs "div01" e "div02" e mostrar a "div...N" que contém o texto pesquisado

Será que é possivel fazer isso com jquery?
se for alguem poderia me ajudar comisso?

Agradece!

Luz e paz!

Answer (score 1):

O que quer pode ser feito com `.hide()` e `.show()`, aliado com a seleção da `div` em que o `p` está com o `.parent()`:

```js
  $("#textFind").keyup(function(){
    var stringPesquisa = $(this).val();
    $('p').parent().hide();
    $('p:contains('+stringPesquisa+')').parent().show()
  });
```

```css
div{
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #333;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textFind">
<br>
<div id="div01" style="">
  <p> esse texto está aqui para ser pesquisado.</p>
  <p> esse outro texto também vai ser pesquisado.</p>
  <p> texto que vai ser que o usuario vai pesquisar digitando no input.</p>
</div>
<div id="div02" style="">
  <p> esse paragrafo deve aparecer se o texto didigtado estiver nessa div.</p>
  <p> esse outro parágrafo vai obedece ao mesmo cirterio.</p>
  <p> o usuario vai digitar no input e essa div deve aparecer.</p>
</div>
<div id="div03" style="">
  <p> esse paragrafo deve aparecer se o texto didigtado estiver nessa div.</p>
  <p> esse outro parágrafo vai obedece ao mesmo cirterio.</p>
  <p> o usuario vai digitar no input e essa div deve aparecer.</p>
</div>
<div id="div04" style="">
  <p> esse paragrafo deve aparecer se o texto didigtado estiver nessa div.</p>
  <p> esse outro parágrafo vai obedece ao mesmo cirterio.</p>
  <p> o usuario vai digitar no input e essa div deve aparecer.</p>
</div>
```

Vale ressaltar que o `.parent()` só funiona neste caso de a iv que quer mostrar/esconder seja o primeiro elemento em um nível hierárquico acima do parágrafo. Caso contrário deve usar [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) e selecionar uma classe geral para todas `div`.

Comment: valeu mano @Samir Braga!
vai bem no rumo do que eu estava procurando, claro que é só o exemplo, mas ajudou pakas.